# Why is `getNumPartitions()` not giving me the correct number of partitions specified by `repartition`?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partition, hadoop-partitioning

I have a `textFile` in and RDD like so: `sc.textFile(<file_name>)`.

I try to repartition the RDD in order to speed up processing:

`sc.repartition(<n>)`.

No matter what I put in for `<n>`, it does not seem to change, as indicated by:

`RDD.getNumPartitions()` always prints the same number `(3)` no matter what.

How do I change the number of partitions to increase performance?

Comment: could you check your config and make sure you have enough executor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because RDDs are *immutable*.
You cannot **change** the partitions of an RDD, but you can create a new one with the desired number of partitions.

```
scala> val a = sc.parallelize( 1 to 1000)
a: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at  parallelize at <console>:21
scala> a.partitions.size
res2: Int = 4
scala> val b = a.repartition(6)
b: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[4] at repartition at <console>:23
scala> a.partitions.size
res3: Int = 4
scala> b.partitions.size
res4: Int = 6
```